# can you identify this plant?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I would like to learn how this plant is called. It grew together with the beans I had planted. The body of the plant grew overnight while the leaves took a couple of days to develop. I decided to keep it in a small pot I had laying around to see if it will develop any further....

[image: Plant]

Comment: These are cotyledons from some species of dicot. However, many species of dicots have *very* similarly shaped (in this case having a retuse tip) and sized cotyledons. You will almost certainly not be able to ID this plant unless you allow it to grow to the point that its first **true leaves** (those that have the "normal" morphology characteristic of your species) have grown. These should follow soon after the cotyledons if the plant is properly cared for. DO NOT damage the plant if you want to be able to properly ID this species. Please update us when true leaves have grown.

Comment: @theforestecologist - Shucks. I thought I said that...

Comment: @anongoodnurse oops sorry missed that. I wasn't going to comment at all and was just going to wait this question out until the OP (hopefully) posted new pictures showing the true leaves. I just saw someone had posted an answer making a guess (I admittedly only read down to your first picture), so I thought it was a good time to clarify in the comments that these cotyledons would make ID difficult.

Comment: That was some interesting information. I didn't know that some plans' first leaves do not represent the final ones! I will wait for it to grow and I will post a picture of its real leaves. Thanks again!

Comment: @GeorgeTsak Any luck growing true leaves?? :)

Comment: @theforestecologist Unfortunately the plant got hit by direct sun and it dried up within a couple of days...

Answer (score 2):

Looks a lot like a radish seedling to me.

[image]

However, if I'm not mistaken, it doesn't even have its first true leaves yet, making identification *very tenuous*.

It can also be any number of *brassica* species, e.g. mustard (l) or cabbage (r):

[image] [image]

If you can't wait to see what it grows into, smash one of the "leaves" between your thumb and a finger. If it's a radish, it will smell like one. If it does, taste the other leaf. If it tastes radishy, you have your answer without waiting. If you want to wait, however, doing that would kill the seedling.

Brassica seedlings will also taste spicy, but not like a radish.

Based on the number of "weeds" in the brassica family, I'd guess it belongs in that group.

I included these diverse possibilities to illustrate how difficult identifying a plant without true leaves is. :)

Comment: Good picture examples showing the similarities of plant "seedling" cotyledons. I agree that specific ID is tenuous if not impossible. However, as I commented under the OP's question, I'd recommend NOT crushing the "leaves" and instead waiting for true leaves to grow in order to have a better chance of IDing the species.

Comment: I think it's a mustard too. But mustard shoots have whiter and weaker stems, right?